# Relative path in InputStream

Tags: java, inputstream

I have two questions.

1. How to use the file `Export.xlsx` lying in the directory `res/`
   instead this

   `try ( FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\student3\\"+sfilename+".xlsx"))`
2. Read data from file, which is lying in the same directory where `.jar` archieve.

What i  tried?

for 1st. q.

```
String path = "res/"+sfilename+".xlsx";
System.out.println(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(path).toString());
File file2 = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(path).toString());
try ( FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file2))

file:/C:/Users/student/IdeaProjects/batch/out/production/batch/res/ExportBatch.xlsx
Work is finished!
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\Users\student3\IdeaProjects\batch\out\production\batch\res\ExportBatch.xlsx (Синтаксическая ошибка в имени файла, имени папки или метке тома)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at workhere.WriterXlsx.<init>(WriterXlsx.java:20)
    at workhere.Start.start(Start.java:62)
    at workhere.Start.main(Start.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

[image]

Comment: where is res folder with respect to your jar?

Comment: @user2067771 post is updated

Comment: Q1 : "../res/ExportBatch.xlsx"
Q2 : just the file name

Comment: nothing here.... reserved

Comment: I'm sorry I can't understand.

Comment: i just reserved this comment for futher dialog. 
@user2067771 Q2 : just the file name, it not helps me.. 
`try(FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("New"+sfilename+".xlsx");)`
not create a new file New(sfilename).xlsx in the same directory

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37257/discussion-between-eldar-and-user2067771)

Comment: oops) better here. If i indicate full path, it works correctly
`try(FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\student3\\"+sfilename+".xlsx"); )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the way.

The method `ClassLoader.getResource` returns a `URL` object. Your `System.out.println` statement prints out this URL. You can see the URL protocol "file:".

Problem: The `File` constructor does not expect a URL, but just the path to the file. This is the reason, why the `FileInputStream` cannot find the file.

Solution: You do not need to create an `InputStream` yourself. Just use `URL.openStream` for that. Or even better: Ask the class loader for it with `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream`.

Example:

```
String path = "res/" + sfilename + ".xlsx";
URL resURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(path);
try (InputStream inputStream = resURL.openStream()) {
    ...
}
```

Or:

```
String path = "res/" + sfilename + ".xlsx";
try (InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path)) {
    ...
}
```